# Infopath form layout colours looks different in browser

Tags: 2013, infopath

When I originally created my infopath form, the background was gray. I changed the background colour to "no fill" and it looks find the the designer/preview but when it's published and viewed in the browser the form has random gray cells. Is there a way to fix this without redoing the entire form?

I tried changing the background color to white/some other colour and the grey cells persists.

I have already attempted to clear the my infopath cache, which did fix the issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in another forum. To clear out all the grey-filled cells, I had to change all the borders in my form to "none".

Right-click a table -> Borders and Shading... -> Borders Tab -> under Presets: None

re-adding the borders did not make the random gray cells come back.